# trouble with unwanted space between divs

Tags: php, css

I have some space that I don't want between classes.

Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4YSXv/

it should be a box without any spaces in between:

[image: Example]

I can't figure out how to erase this space, i googled it of course and apparently it's a common problem, but all solutions I found didn't help me.

**HTML**

```
       <div class='image'>
       </div>
       <div class='line1'>
       </div>
       <div class='head'>
       </div>
       <div class='subBox'>
          <div class='sub'></div>
          <div class='price'></div>
          <div class='button'></div>
       </div>
       <div style='clear:both;'></div>

       <div class='line2'>
       </div>
       </div>
</div>
<div class='placeholder'>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.headerimage {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    height:273px;
    background-color:#000000;
}
.box1 {
    position:relative;
    top:273px;
}
.produkt {
    width:224px;
    height:318px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}
.image {
    width:224px;
    height:230px;
    background-color:#afeeee;
    position:relative;
}
.line1 {
    width:224px;
    height:1px;
    background-color:#000000;
    position:relative;
}
.head {
    width:224px;
    height:25px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    position:relative;
}
.subBox {
    width:224px;
    height:50px;
    position:relative;
}
.sub {
    width:224px;
    height:25px;
    position:relative;
}
.price {
    width:160px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:#847077;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}
.button {
    width:58px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:#6A5ACD;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}
.line2 {
    width:224px;
    height:5px;
    background-color:#000000;
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:20px;
}
.placeholder {
    height:800px;
    width:800px;
    position:relative;
    padding-top:1000px;
}
```

Comment: Did you add a `* {margin: 0; padding 0;}` at the beginning of your CSS?

Comment: To reset all margins and paddings that the browser adds by default. Add it before any other CSS code.

Comment: Yes, but it didn't change.

Comment: Make sure you have your backgrounds correct. You have a few lines like `background-color:` and no value behind it

Comment: Please post a fiddle with your code and your CSS and markup.

Comment: @Hidde as far as I know that's no longer recommended. Rather use YUI for a reset http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

Comment: do you want .sub,.price,.button side by side or vertically

Comment: @Gangadhar All divs are in the right position, only the space in between is the problem.
This is how it should look like: http://tinypic.com/r/24gvn9y/5

Comment: @hidde http://jsfiddle.net/m5t6e/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.sub {
    width: 224px;    
    position: relative;    
}
```

you are getting the white space of 20px from the height of the .sub

Also height of the

```
.subBox {
width: 224px;
height: 20px;
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Now I have a new problem…for my layout, I need to multiply this box 8 times like this: http://tinypic.com/r/sc826t/5

It worked before, but now (after I erased the height) I get this: http://tinypic.com/r/ra67g9/5

Comment: Can you give the html for this so that i can see where the problem is

Comment: your jsfiddle is incomplete

Answer (score 1):

```
.subBox {
    position: relative;
    width: 224px;
}
.sub {
    position: relative;
    width: 224px;
}
```