# trouble with layout/float:left

Tags: css, css-float

I just asked this question '[trouble with unwanted space between divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17744885/trouble-with-unwanted-space-between-divs)'

Now I have a new problem…for my layout, I need to multiply this box 8 times like this:
[image]

It worked before, but now (after I erased the height) I get this:

[image]

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m5t6e/
and here's the code:

HTML (repeats 8 times) :

```
<div class='image'></div>
<div class='line1'></div>
<div class='head'></div>
<div class='subBox'>
    <div class='sub'></div>
    <div class='price'></div>
    <div class='button'></div>
</div>
<div style='clear:both;'></div>
<div class='line2'></div>
<div class='placeholder'></div>
```

CSS:

```
.headerimage {
    background-color:#000;
    height:273px;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
.box1 {
    position:relative;
    top:273px;
}
.produkt {
    float:left;
    height:318px;
    position:relative;
    width:224px;
}
.image {
    background-color:#afeeee;
    height:230px;
    position:relative;
    width:224px;
}
.line1 {
    background-color:#000;
    height:1px;
    position:relative;
    width:224px;
}
.head {
    background-color:#eee;
    height:25px;
    position:relative;
    width:224px;
}
.subBox {
    height:50px;
    position:relative;
    width:224px;
}
.sub {
    height:25px;
    position:relative;
    width:224px;
}
.price {
    background-color:#847077;
    float:left;
    height:20px;
    position:relative;
    width:160px;
}
.button {
    background-color:#6A5ACD;
    float:left;
    height:20px;
    position:relative;
    width:58px;
}
.line2 {
    background-color:#000;
    height:5px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    position:relative;
    width:224px;
}
.placeholder{
    height:800px;
    width:800px;
    position:relative;
    padding-top:1000px;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Remove `.placehodler` CSS style
2. Encapsulate each element in a `div`
3. Set encapsulated `div` to `float:left` and behave like `display:inline-block` div
4. insert a `<br>` after each 4 blocks

**Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/achudars/m5t6e/1/)**

Comment: with 8 elements: http://jsfiddle.net/achudars/m5t6e/2/ (be sure to expand the panel)